# Spring-data-elasticsearch @CompletionField does not create mapping type Completion

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using annotation [@CompletionField](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/annotations/CompletionField.html) from Spring Data Elasticsearch (4.0.1 RELEASE) in my entity, but it looks the ElasticSearch index is created with wrong mapping.

**Entity**

```
@Document(indexName="address")
public class Address {
    @CompletionField
    private String cityName;
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Service
public interface AddressRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
}
```

Index is autocreated by calling `repository.save(address)`

**Snippet from elasticsearch mapping**

```
"cityName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}
```

As you can see there is missing type "completion" (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester).

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@CompletionField` must be of type `Completion`:

```
@Document(indexName="address")
public class Address {

    @CompletionField
    private Completion cityName;

}
```

You might want to check the [test code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/completion) for this functionality